# How to use location in Nextjs 13+ SSR and clinet side components?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to simply show an active link in header navigation.
In next < 13 I was using `useRoute()`. However, useRoute() is not working in 13+.
Another problem is that `useRoute` is not mounted if you are using SSR.

So, my workaround was to make sure, that global layout is client-side component.
Global layout:

```
'use client';

import * as React from 'react';
import {Footer, Header, Sidebar} from '../components';

import '../styles/globals.css';

export default function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    return <html>
        <body>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <Header pathname={window ? window.location.pathname : ''}/>
                <Sidebar/>
                <>
                    {children}
                </>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
}
```

The nav condition:

```
<nav className={styles.navigation}>
    <ul>
                {URL.map(route => <li key={route.path}>
                    <Link
                        className={route.path === pathname ? styles.highlighted : ''}
                        href={route.path}
                    >
                        {route.name}
                    </Link>
                </li>)}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But it doesn't work correctly, and the url is `active` only after the page refresh.
No props inside pages or layouts could give me the desired behaviour.

I would assume this is something simple, but I struggle to find how to do that **both on client side and with SSR**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`usePathname`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-pathname) which can be used client side only.

> This hook is not available in Server Components. It does not accept any arguments.

here is how, in `Header` component remove the `pathname` prop and do this:

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Header() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      {URL.map((route, index) => (
        <Link
          key={index}
          href={route.path}
          className={route.path === pathname ? styles.highlighted : '' }
        >
          {route.name}
        </Link>
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

you can see a working example here
[image: Edit reverent-pateu-2w1d9b]

Comment: I've just got it in the docs, but still, thank you for the answer!